# getting error on playing a basic audio in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-audioplayers

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

class Button extends StatelessWidget {
  const Button({Key? key, required this.number}) : super(key: key);
  final String number;

  void playAudio() async {
    final audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
    final path = AssetSource('audios/$number.wav');

    await audioPlayer.play(path);

    audioPlayer.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          playAudio(); // Call the function to play audio
        },
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          minimumSize: const Size(double.infinity, double.infinity),
        ),
        child: Text(number),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Error:

> V/MediaPlayer(30587): resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
> V/MediaPlayer(30587): cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
> V/MediaPlayer(30587): resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
> V/MediaPlayer(30587): cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
> V/MediaPlayer(30587): resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
> V/MediaPlayer(30587): cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null

I want to play the audio